Problem with Register Activity with firebase
I built a login page and had it registered to firebase with one user. Recently, i tried to sign up and register more users but i encountered a problem. It refuses to register more users, the reason it is behaving like that, I cannot say. Did anyone encounter such problems and how did you solve it? Please see below my Register Activity code and build gradle using java. I'm using Chipmunk version 2021 of android studio.
            btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.button);
            email = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
            phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.inputPhone);
            password = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
            textLogin = findViewById(R.id.account);
            userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            textLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActvity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
            });
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = database.getReference("users");
            String inputEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            String inputPhone = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
            String User = userName.getText().toString();
            if (inputEmail.isEmpty()) {
                email.setError("Email can not be empty");
            }
            if (User.isEmpty()) {
                userName.setError("User can not be empty");
            }
            if (pass.isEmpty()) {
                password.setError("Min password length should 6 characters");
            }
            if (inputPhone.isEmpty()) {
                phoneNumber.setError("linenumber can not be empty");
            } else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new 
            OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActvity.this, "User registered Successfully", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActvity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActvity.this, "Registration Failed" + 
            task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
            });
            HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass(phoneNumber, email, userName, 
            password);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("userName").setValue(User);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("email").setValue(inputEmail);                
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("phoneNumber").setValue
            (inputPhone);reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("password").
            setValue(pass);
            }
            }
            });
            }
            }

            
            buildscript {
            dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
            }
            }// Top-level build file where you can add configuration 
            options common to all sub-projects/modules.
            plugins {
            id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
            id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
            }
            allprojects {
            repositories {
            }    
            }
            task clean(type: Delete) 
            {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
            }

